# Two Forms in a view Cakephp

Tags: validation, cakephp

two forms in one view Login,Register

the register :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('class'=>'box','action'=>'register')); ?>
```

the login :

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('User',array('class'=>'box','action'=>'login')); ?>
```

The code is written in the Login view , and i'm using custom validation , the login works perfectly because I'm in the Login view (i guess) , But when i submit the Register Form it takes me away to another page : /users/register 
how can i stop that.

Secondly , since both of the Forms have username and password fields they are affecting each other , I mean when I write a wrong username and password , they don't disappear after validation and that's ok but they appears also in the register Form , and that's not !

Comment: You define the 'action' => 'register', it means that he will send data to the register method in your users contoller.

Comment: true , because the register() is the function that should handle these data , I mean what could I do else ?

Comment: I want to stay in the same page after clicking register

Comment: Then use ajax or try $this -> redirect($this -> referer());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still another approach

Just add a hidden field to your forms to indicate which form has been sent;

```
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('class'=>'box','action'=>'register')); 
echo $this->Form->hidden('formsent', array('value' => 'register'));
echo $this->Form->end('Register');


echo $this->Form->create('User',array('class'=>'box','action'=>'register'));
echo $this->Form->hidden('formsent', array('value' => 'login'));
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
```

And inside your controller, just one controller;

```
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ('register' === $this->request->data['Tblforumuser']['formsent']) {
            //register

        } else {
            // login
            if ($this->User->validates(array('fieldList' => array('email', 'password')))) {

            } else {

            }
        }
    }
```

on
The ‘on’ key can be set to either one of the following values: ‘update’ or ‘create’. This provides a mechanism that allows a certain rule to be applied either during the creation of a new record, or during update of a record.

If a rule has defined ‘on’ => ‘create’, the rule will only be enforced during the creation of a new record. Likewise, if it is defined as ‘on’ => ‘update’, it will only be enforced during the updating of a record.

example in your validation:

```
'email' => array(
    'required' => array(
        'on'         => 'create',
        'rule'       => 'notEmpty',
        'message'    => 'Enter your email address',
        'required'   => true,
        'last'       => true
    )
```

Comment: well that's clever and foxy way , thanks.  
but what about the validation when i write wrong username in the register the validation shows up also in the login form. 
does that solve it ?

Comment: How I can help you if I dont know what happend in your model or in your controller. your question is theoretical. would be a separate question about the error committed when applying these